# Javascript OOP, getters, setters, run - D3.js - make graph resuable by option settings

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I tried myself but oviously I am not good enough to make this work :-) What I would like to achieve is similar to Mike's reusability talks - http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/ :

```
marbles = new Marbles();
marbles.width();//getter, setter
marbles.height();//-||-
...etc
marbles.run();//run the code
```

Code is example is shown below. Could someone help me please? I know how to make classes and OOP in Java or PHP, but pure JS is not my area of expertise :-)

I have this code:

```
//initialize on (menu click)
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


       marbles();


    });
});
```

with variables and main function:

```
function marbles(){
    var height = 500,
        width = 1000;    


       var path = "";
```

**..another vars (about 15)**

```
       var force = d3.layout.force()        
          .size([width, height]);
       //foci to be set for relation type positioning and nodes placing

       var links = force.links(),
          nodes = force.nodes();


      run();

     //graph starts here by loading data - d3.xml
     function run (rootNode){

     begin();


     }

    //internal timer function - adding nodes one at the time
    function begin(clickedNode){  

   }

   //classical update function
   function update() {

   }

}
```

Thanks

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do OOP in JS. You can find them in books
by JS gurus

If you just want to understand how several charts work, please
take a look at how Bob Monteverde implemented the models in his chart library...
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/tree/gh-pages/src/models
I think you will learn a lot of things from his code.

There are also various examples of reusable charts in this google group threads:
[https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/reusable$20charts/d3js/6VSl7srPYIo/iKNkxSr1YF0J](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/reusable%2420charts/d3-js/6VSl7srPYIo/iKNkxSr1YF0J)

Comment: Thanks. I know that. Most of these I have even seen :-) My problem is that neither of the solution I tried did not work. What I need realy badly is to let the user just set the variables BEFORE the graph runs. No need to draw multiple graphs though.

Comment: well, I would suggest to just take one of those examples and play with it, add variables to it, set them, modify them....and repeat this until you understand how it's done.... if you still don't get it, try reading: http://killdream.github.com/blog/2011/10/understanding-javascript-oop or kangax's blog or other stuff about